# Rails to_json include a method has args

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my Rails app,I have following codes:

`MemAccount` Mode

```
class MemAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :current_mem
  def followstatus
    SntFollow.where({:from_id=> current_mem.id}).pluck('to_id').include? id
  end 
end
```

Controller:

```
def search
  _items = MemAccount.select(:avatar,:nc,:id,:followers).where("nc like '%#{params[:search]}%'")
  render json:{
    :items => _items
  }.to_json(:methods=>["followstatus"])
end
```

How can I set the MemAccount instance attr `current_mem` for the  mem lists,not one mem.I want to find a best way to realize this,thanks!

to be honest,I want to write like this:

```
class MemAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  def followstatus me
    SntFollow.where({:from_id=> me.id}).pluck('to_id').include? id
  end 
end

 def search
  _items = MemAccount.select(:avatar,:nc,:id,:followers).where("nc like '%#{params[:search]}%'")
  render json:{
    :items => _items
  }.to_json(:methods=>["followstatus(#{current_mem})"])
end
```

But the result is like:

```
{"items":[{"avatar":"tx.png","nc":"","id":1,"followers":1}...]}
```

I cant't find the attr `followstatus`,why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use to https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers to serialize the object as per your need. Its handy and very helpfull. And use `respond_with` and `respond_to` insted for `format.json`

You can create serializer as

```
class AccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :name, :method_name, :instane_method_name

 def method_name
  "value"
 end
end
```

and in controller

```
respond_with @accounts, each_serializer: AccountSerializer
```

Comment: This will not work,because the `value` is from session,so,if many users visit this,what the value should be,the session is different,

Comment: so,please see my question addition,I want to realize `.to_json(:methods=>["followstatus(#{current_mem})"])`

Comment: You are not passing any current_user to the model/instance. You can use session value in serializer from scope.